# Opening CSV as worksheet with VBA - incorrect parsing

Tags: excel, csv, vba

I have some `file.csv`. If I open it by double-click, it opens in Excel with the proper setup (there are no semicolons and each "line" of data is correctly showing up in the expected columns).

Example result:

[image]

However, in VBA:

```
'Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=f, StartRow:=2, DataType:=xlDelimited, Semicolon:=True, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, TextQualifier:=xlTextQualifierNone
'Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=f, DataType:=xlDelimited, Semicolon:=True
'Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=f, DataType:=xlDelimited
'Workbooks.Open Filename:=f, Format:=xlDelimited, Delimiter:=Chr(34)
'Workbooks.Open Filename:=f, Format:=xlDelimited, Delimiter:=";"
Workbooks.Open Filename:=f, Format:=xlDelimited
Dim s As String
s = """" & ";" & """"
Workbooks.Open Filename:=f, Format:=xlDelimited, Delimiter:=s
'Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=f, DataType:=xlDelimited, OtherChar:=s
'Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=f, DataType:=xlDelimited, OtherChar:=";"
```

I've tried the lines above (and a number of others before I started keeping all my attempts) as well as without any arguments at all, but no matter what I do, the file will open without the text being split as it does when I double-click the file.

Example result:

[image]

So in summary; double-clicking the file parses the file correctly, `Open` and `OpenText` does not. Surprisingly, the worksheet looks identical regardless of using `Open` or `OpenText`.

A similar problem is described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13746404/opening-csv-in-excel-using-vba-causes-data-to-appear-in-two-columns-instead-of-o), though it remains without a proper answer. The difference between our cases is that Excel won't parse *anything* for me, where it seems like it does parse large parts of the file for OP.

I just want to open the workbook and iterate over one of the columns, then close it. I have a couple of workarounds in mind, so I will be able to solve it one unnecessarily roundabout way or another.

So far I have found these ideas:

1. Renaming `.csv` to `.txt` and using `OpenText`
2. Using `QueryTable` import
3. Iterating over the borked file as it appears using `OpenText` and using `LEFT`/`MID`/`RIGHT` to get at the desired column(s)
4. Binary `Open` and `Split` each line into an array

**Desired answers:**

1. How to achieve this solution using `Workbooks.OpenText` or similar native function.
2. Explanations (or maybe even ideas) as to why `Workbooks.OpenText` and/or the most appropriate native function similar to it cannot achieve the desired result when Excel itself does seem to be capable of it.
3. Other workarounds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @GarysStudent for inadvertently tipping me off as to the one attribute I had not been smart enough to try. They said "assigning special meaning to the .csv extension".

Turns out that localization impacts this "special meaning" in the `.csv` context. I am using a localized version of Excel and setting `Local:=True` enables both `Open` and `OpenText` to parse the file correctly, even without specifying `;` as a delimiter.

Answer (score 4):

If you are going to use VBA to import the file, just use VBA to parse the records:

```
Sub ImportFile()
   Dim j As Long, k As Long
    Close #1
    Open "C:\TestFolder\whatever.csv" For Input As #1
    j = 1
     Do While Not EOF(1)
            Line Input #1, TextLine
            ary = Split(TextLine, ";")
            k = 1
            For Each a In ary
               Cells(k, j) = a
               k = k + 1
            Next a
            j = j + 1
    Loop
    Close #1
End Sub
```

Doing it this way stops VBA from assigning special meaning to  the *.csv* extension.

Once the core code is working to your satisfaction, you can decorate it with other features like double-quote encapsulation, etc.